# How can I track the posts I downvoted, that have been edited afterwards?

Tags: discussion, voting

This question, to some extent, is applicable to all SE sites, but I believe that Politics.SE may need addressing this more than the other sites of SE family, due to the very nature of the topics we discuss.

So, a typical situation, [mentioned here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/139/2984):

1. *Alice* writes a post (whether it is Q or A);
2. *Bob* finds some problem with the post. *Bob* downvotes the post with a comment stating the problem;
3. *Charlie* sees *Bob's* comment, agrees with argument within, downvoting the post, too;
4. *Alice* is convinced with *Bob's* argument and fixes the problem;

Question: **How does *Charlie* know that the post has been edited to undownvote the post?**

Background: Unlike the other SE sites, we have a higher number of imperfect, opinionated, or emotional posts (IMO).
Ability to improve is a powerful tool, and this is the ultimate reason for voting.
Being able to **reward the improved post** seems to be even more important than voting for a newly written one.

How can this be done, using either SE features or some non-burdensome technique?
I mean, I don't want to bookmark all posts I have ever downvoted and revision them time-to-time.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are worried about downvoting a post and possibility of your having to undownvote it, you don't need to downvote any post immediately. Just leave a comment and you can downvote it later if it has not been edited.
2. When I downvote a post, I don't care what happens next. Your downvote still stands as it was done when the post lacked research and was neither useful nor clear. After the post is edited, other users might upvote it on behalf of you. You don't need to check every single downvote you cast and cancel or reverse it.
3. If you really want to do that, you can bookmark it under your own folder or favorite it so that you can search it using your [favourites under Activity](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2984/bytebuster?tab=favorites).
4. You can view all the posts you've downvoted clicking on [downvote under X votes cast](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2984/bytebuster?tab=votes&sort=downvote). Note that I don't have access to the information on the link because it is private.

Comment: (4) is great. (1) "you don't need to downvote any post immediately", good point. How do I remember **bad posts** then to turn back and downvote? (2) is not convincing, sorry: I downvote **not to punish** but to encourage improvement. Once it becomes improved, my remaining downvote is harmful as it undermines the whole reason for editing bad posts. Indeed, why would you bother if the votes stay sticky? (3) — it's a nice feature, have to think on it; I have several "levels" of my SE activity: Favs are for informative posts I want to check daily; a downvote can wait till weekend, for example.

Comment: @bytebuster If you want to improve the quality of Politics SE, don't hesitate to downvote any post. It not only encourages OPs to edit the post, but also helps to clean up the site. How many OPs have you seen who have responded to your comments? Based on my experience, I haven't seen many, especially among new users. You have your own way while others do have their own.

Comment: Let's stick to the topic. I set *what* I want to accomplish and *why*, and now I'm genuinely asking *how* can this be done. Your item (4) looks promising for now.

Answer (score 1):

On your profile, you'll find a list of votes. So click on where you see your medals on the top, then *activity*, *votes* and then *downvotes*.

If we say that you're Charlie, look at

https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2984/bytebuster?tab=votes&sort=downvote

It seems that only you can see the content of that list. At least I can't (though I can see mine).

Comment: Your post is a duplicate of No. 4 in my answer.

Comment: Indeed. I read your post too quickly. If you add the information on how anyone can find it (my first paragraph), I'll delete mine.